# How do I set the base level for an interaction term when building a generalized linear model in R?

Tags: r

When I include the factor1, factors2, and its interaction, the interaction term has the combination of each's base level as its base level. However, if I include interaction term only (factor1:factor2 instead of factor1*factor2), the combination of last level of both is used as reference (i.e. this row has "NA" for estimate, std error etc). I have checked multiple times that each factor has the right base level configured before building the model. Is there a way to make the combination of each's first level to be the reference? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and the code you are running so we can more clearly see the problem and test possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what's going on here.

```
(dd <- expand.grid(f1=letters[1:2],f2=LETTERS[1:2]))
##   f1 f2
## 1  a  A
## 2  b  A
## 3  a  B
## 4  b  B
```

Add a response variable:

```
dd2 <- data.frame(dd,y=c(1,2,3,5))
```

Use `model.matrix()` to look at what dummy variables get constructed.

```
data.frame(dd,model.matrix(~f1*f2,data=dd),check.names=FALSE)
##   f1 f2 (Intercept) f1b f2B f1b:f2B
## 1  a  A           1   0   0       0
## 2  b  A           1   1   0       0
## 3  a  B           1   0   1       0
## 4  b  B           1   1   1       1
```

So the baseline (intercept) is the `a:A` combination; the `f1b` parameter is the `a-b` contrast when `f2==A`; the `f2B` parameter is the `A-B` contrast when `f1==a`; and the interaction is the contrast between `bB-aA`, given the additive expectation.

If we add the interaction explicitly, R doesn't know to drop the intercept column.  In this overparameterized model matrix, there isn't really a "baseline" level, but when there is rank-deficiency, R does drop the *last* column by default, so you end up effectively getting `bB` as your baseline (since the `bB` row of the matrix is `[1 0 0 0]` if we drop the last column).

```
data.frame(dd,X3 <- model.matrix(~f1:f2,data=dd),check.names=FALSE)
## f1 f2 (Intercept) f1a:f2A f1b:f2A f1a:f2B f1b:f2B
## 1  a  A           1       1       0       0       0
## 2  b  A           1       0       1       0       0
## 3  a  B           1       0       0       1       0
## 4  b  B           1       0       0       0       1
```

If you want to use a specified model matrix, you can cheat and do this directly.  You have to remember that if you don't specify `-1` in the formula, R will automatically re-add an intercept column, so here we get rid of the first two columns (`y~.` says "use all the variables in the data frame, except the response variable, as predictors").

```
dd3 <- data.frame(y=dd2$y,X3[,-(1:2)])
coef(lm(y~.,data=dd3))
```

Looking at the model matrix above but leaving out the second column, we interpret this as:

- `(Intercept)` (`[1 0 0 0]`) is the value of `a-A`
- `f1b:f2A` (`[1 1 0 0]`) is the `a-b` contrast when `f2=A`
- `f1a:f2B` (`[1 0 1 0]`) is the `A-B` contrast when `f1=a`
- the interaction is now the straight contrast between `b-B` and `a-A`, but *uncorrected* for the additive effects.  Is that really what you wanted?